# Solving logarithmic eqn with $x^2$

Tags: logarithms, quadratics

Full question:

Solve the equation:
$$\log_5{(x+1)} = \log_{25}{(4x^2)} - \log_2{0.5}^3$$

So,

$\log_5{(x+1)} = \log_{25}{(4x^2)} + \log_2{2}^3$

$\log_5{(x+1)} = \log_{25}{(4x^2)} + 3$

$\log_5{(x+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\log_{5}{(4x^2)} + 3$

$\log_5{(x+1)} = \log_{5}{(2x)} + \log_55^3$

So,

$x+1 = 250x$

$249x = 1$

$x= \frac{1}{249} $

This is the answer provided by the examiner but I have been playing around with a graphing application and it shows that there is a negative answer of $-\frac{1}{251}$. Why is it so?

Comment: $\log t^2=2\log t$ is not true when $t$ is negative. You need to handle this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost one solution when you assumed that $4x^2 = (2x)^2$. It could just as well be $(-2x)^2$, leading to $\log_5(x+1) = \log_5(-2x) + 3$. This is, of course, only meaningful when $-1<x<0$, but it does lead to the solution $x = -\frac{1}{251}$

Comment: Based on 'O' Level syllabus, the negative answer should be included right?(Current level I'm studying)

But isn't $r\log(t)$ = $\log(t)^r$ based on the logarithms power law?

Comment: I think you should include the negative solution regardless of level (unless it's specifically stated in the problem text that $x$ is positive or something). Also, I _am_ using the power law. In one case, we have $\log_5((2x)^2) = 2\log_5(2x)$, while in the other case we have $\log_5((-2x)^2) = 2\log_5(-2x)$. In both cases the $2$ cancels the $\frac12$, and you can solve your equation.

Comment: Hmm,thanks a lot! So, if the power is even, we must consider both the positive and negative.(Textbook didn't illustrate such a thing also)

Comment: Yes, that's right. And that's a shame about your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

First we have to find a 'domain' for this equation:
$$x+1>0 \wedge 4x^2>0$$
Thus the domain is 
$$D=(-1,\infty)\backslash\{0\}$$

Now from $$\log_5(x+1)=\frac{1}{2}\log_5(4x^2)+3$$ we can have two cases:

1. $\log_5(x+1)=\log_5(2x)+3$ - the domain in this cases is $D_1 = (0,\infty)$ and the result is provided by You ($x=\frac{1}{249}\in D_1$)
2. $\log_5(x+1)=\log_5(-2x)+3$ - in this case $D_2=(-1,0)$ and the result is $x=-\frac{1}{251}\in D_2$

Both results are in $D$, thus the result of yor equation is
$$x\in\left\{-\frac{1}{251}, \frac{1}{249}\right\}$$